# STS Exception when opening xml bean configuration file

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I get the following error consistently when opening STS. To reproduce, I have a bean configuration file open in the editor and I exit STS. Then I re-open STS and this exception is thrown and the editor I had open does not start correctly.

If I close the editor throwing the error and then re-open it (without restarting STS), the editor is able to open fine. But then when restarting STS it will still throw this error.

The content of my bean configuration is mostly Spring Integration elements. Here are the schemas I am using:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

The only non-Spring Integration elements are 2 inner-bean definitions for a custom router and a custom transformer:

```xml
<int:router id="myrouter" input-channel="routerInput">
    <bean class="my.example.Router">
        <property name="prop" ref="otherBean"/>
    </bean>
</int:router>

<int:transformer input-channel="transformerInput" output-channel="OutboundMail" >
    <bean class="my.example.Transformer">            
        <property name="prop" ref="otherBean"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>
```

Stacktrace:

```
eclipse.buildId=3.6.0.201407101106-RELEASE-e44  
java.version=1.7.0_45  
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation  
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US  
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide  
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide  

This is a continuation of log file U:\Users\fgreg\Documents\Workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log  
Created Time: 2014-08-20 07:57:08.801  

org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata  
Error  
Wed Aug 20 08:00:16 EDT 2014  
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata".  

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanName' must not be empty  
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:162)  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:58)  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:46)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.AbstractBeanMethodOverride.<init>(AbstractBeanMethodOverride.java:37)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeanLookupMethodOverride.<init>(BeanLookupMethodOverride.java:24)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.Bean.initBean(Bean.java:373)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.Bean.getProperty(Bean.java:192)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.SpringDataUtils.isRepositoryBean(SpringDataUtils.java:108)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.metadata.ui.RepositoriesBeanMetadataProvider.provideBeanMetadata(RepositoriesBeanMetadataProvider.java:52)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.internal.model.BeanMetadataBuilderJob$1.run(BeanMetadataBuilderJob.java:198)  
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.internal.model.BeanMetadataBuilderJob.attachMetadataToBean(BeanMetadataBuilderJob.java:191)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.internal.model.BeanMetadataBuilderJob.attachMetadata(BeanMetadataBuilderJob.java:170)  
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.internal.model.BeanMetadataBuilderJob.run(BeanMetadataBuilderJob.java:141)  
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Has anyone seen this before or know how to fix it?

---

Larger stacktrace from the log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-08-20 07:57:05.848
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanName' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:46)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.AbstractBeanMethodOverride.<init>(AbstractBeanMethodOverride.java:37)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeanLookupMethodOverride.<init>(BeanLookupMethodOverride.java:24)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.Bean.initBean(Bean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.Bean.getProperty(Bean.java:192)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.SpringDataUtils.isRepositoryBean(SpringDataUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.SpringDataUtils.getRepositoryBeansFor(SpringDataUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.SpringDataUtils.getRepositoryBeanIds(SpringDataUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.beans.ui.editor.RepositoriesReferenceableElementLocator.getReferenceableElements(RepositoriesReferenceableElementLocator.java:55)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.editor.util.BeansEditorUtils.getReferenceableNodes(BeansEditorUtils.java:918)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.graph.model.AbstractConfigGraphDiagram.updateRefNodeRegistry(AbstractConfigGraphDiagram.java:342)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.graph.model.AbstractConfigGraphDiagram.refreshModelFromXml(AbstractConfigGraphDiagram.java:331)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.graph.parts.ActivityDiagramPart.refresh(ActivityDiagramPart.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.SimpleRootEditPart.setContents(SimpleRootEditPart.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:626)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.graph.AbstractConfigGraphicalEditor.initializeGraphicalViewer(AbstractConfigGraphicalEditor.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditor.createGraphicalViewer(GraphicalEditor.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditorWithPalette.createPartControl(GraphicalEditorWithPalette.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.addPage(FormEditor.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.addPage(FormEditor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui.editors.AbstractConfigEditor.addConfigEditorPage(AbstractConfigEditor.java:237)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui.editors.AbstractConfigEditor.updateNamespacePages(AbstractConfigEditor.java:936)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui.editors.SpringConfigEditor.updateNamespacePages(SpringConfigEditor.java:189)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui.editors.AbstractConfigEditor.createNamespacePages(AbstractConfigEditor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui.editors.AbstractConfigEditor.addPages(AbstractConfigEditor.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$10.widgetSelected(StackRenderer.java:1035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3110)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1794)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: From the stack trace seems to be something related to Spring Data? Is your editor opened for an xml containing Spring Data config?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I included the schemas I am using, please see the updated question.

Comment: What happen if you change from `spring-integration-jdbc-2.2.xsd` to `spring-integration-jdbc.xsd`? Removing the xsd version.

Comment: "The content of my bean configuration is mostly Spring Integration elements" could you share that content? something would be wrong there too. Perhaps an element without an `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I sort of took the nuclear approach which seems to have fixed the problem. I did 2 things that seemed to have resulted in the issue to resolving itself, I'm not sure which one had greater effect in fixing the problem:

- I added the 'name' attribute to my inner bean elements:

```xml
<int:router id="myrouter" input-channel="routerInput">
    <bean class="my.example.Router" name="router">
        <property name="prop" ref="otherBean"/>
    </bean>
</int:router>

<int:transformer input-channel="transformerInput" output-channel="OutboundMail" >
    <bean class="my.example.Transformer" name="transformer">             
        <property name="prop" ref="otherBean"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>
```

- I wiped out everything in my .settings folder and restarted STS

I thought adding the 'name' to the inner beans is what did it so I removed the attribute and then restarted to see if the error would reappear. It did not reappear. So it was either a combination of doing both of these things or it was wiping out the .settings files that did it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here. But the exception still looks like a bug in STS. Can you file an issue here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS, and maybe attach a sample project that reproduces the problem? That would be awesome!

Comment: @MartinLippert I agree it looks like a bug but it has not re-appeared since I took these actions. If it does start happening again I can try to gather more information. I work on a team of developers that use both Eclipse and STS and not necessarily the same version; our .settings are checked into SVN so I'm wondering if that may have contributed as well.

Comment: Sounds good. But I don't think that the .settings file is involved in here. Thanks!